# Can I use a license with a warranty disclaimer when my country's laws make that inapplicable?

Tags: gpl-3, license-recommendation, law, warranty

I'm studying Computer Science in Germany. Even before the beginning of my studies, I wrote some software in order to learn how to write good code (and in order to have fun, too :-) ).
Now, I'd like to publish some of it (on github) so that I can show it to other people in a convenient way. Additionally, I'm looking forward to receive helpful suggestions, so that I can not only improve my programs, but also my coding style. (And hopefully, some of my projects will turn out to be useful to others, too.)

That's the situation. But I'm not sure how to handle the publication. I'd like to license my software under the GPLv3+, because I like the idea of free software and would be proud to be part of it.

In Germany, however, the "Disclaimer of Warranty" (Nr. 15 of the GPL*) and the "Limitation of Liability" (Nr. 16 of the GPL*) are not applicable for legal reasons. In spite of the fact that I'm distributing the software as individual without commercial interests, there remains some sort of liability and warranty:

> [...] less stringent liability (only for willful intent and gross
>   negligence) and restricted warranty (only for malicious concealment of
>   a defect).
>   (https://www.ifross.org/en/what-legal-standard-liability-and-warranty-germany)

Of course, I do not want to distribute malicious content, but I'm a bit worried about the negligence thing. I'm really trying to write good and stable software, but I'm still a beginner. I already changed the "master" branch of my github repositories to "development" and marked the software as "alpha" short after uploading it (under the GPL).

**Now, my question**:
Is there any software license that is applicable for such educational purposes? Perhaps a license that grants all freedoms (copy, modify, distribute, etc.), but *not* the freedom to actually execute the software (especially in production environments)?
Or are my concerns unjustified? What do you think?

I would be really happy if you would like to give me some advice!

*the text of the GPLv3: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html

Comment: A license that doesn't let you execute the code would violate the Free software/Open source definitions. But how the warranty disclaimers interact with local laws is a good question. Though actually the following covers that well already.